# Painting on QWidget to cover whole widget

Tags: qt, plot, drawing, qwidget, qpainter

I have a QWidget inside a window. The window can be resized and the widget should stretch to cover the maximum area possible. I'm drawing a plot onto this QWidget and I want the plot to stretch with the window. Currently it works, but I feel I could be doing this way cleaner.

This is how it looks:

[image: Before resize]

After resizing this is what I want it to look like:

[image: After resize]

Currently this works, but I'm doing it like this:

In the widgets paintEvent() I calculate the scale factor like this

```
double scaleFactorX = (double) width() / m_xAxis.last();
double scaleFactorY = (double) height() / m_yAxis.last();
```

*Note that m_xAxis.last() is the largest value that will be plotted. And width() and height() return the width and height of the QWidget.

Then when I'm drawing the elements I multiply each point with the scale factor to stretch it to the width of the QWidget. I feel like there's a better (more correct) way of doing this, but I'm not sure what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in an easier / more readable way using by setting a [QTransform](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html) on your QPainter.

Example from the doc (of course you're probably more interested in .scale() than in .translate()):

```
void CombinedTransformation::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue, 1, Qt::DashLine));
    painter.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

    QTransform transform;
    transform.translate(50, 50);
    transform.rotate(45);
    transform.scale(0.5, 1.0);
    painter.setTransform(transform);

    painter.setFont(QFont("Helvetica", 24));
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 1));
    painter.drawText(20, 10, "QTransform");
}
```

Comment: I tried using `QTransform` before, but the problem is it scales font size and line width. So when I draw the grid with line width 2 it turns out too thick.

Comment: so please give full description what you are trying yo achieve (not how you are trying to achieve something).

Comment: I want a plot that stretches with the widget without having to scale every value before draw it. This answer scales everything after drawing.

Comment: And so you should be able to use the QTransform for everything it does the way you want and call QPainter w/o QTransform for the few things you still want to do by hand. Note that you can still use QTransform to compute coordinates even though you write your text on a QPainter w/o QTranform to prevent font size scaling. Also note that QPen.setWidth(0) enables you to draw 1-pixel-wide lines regardless the QTransform (so called cosmetic pen).

Comment: Or in the other hand, if you're just wanting to draw a plot, you can use such freely available widgets: http://www.qcustomplot.com/

Comment: Thanks for your response Jim. I actually used qCustomPlot before but dropped it because it was to slow and heavy for my needs. Also, I'm aware of the QPen.setWidth(0) lines, but I need different size pens so that's out of the option. It really would be nice if there was an option to scale coordinates before drawing. I guess I'll just do it by hand for now. Still, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Didn't really help me, but I appreciate the effort.